# Why do I have to cast a byte as unsigned twice to see hex output?

Tags: c++, casting

I want to print a variable as hex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    auto c = 0xb7;

    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned char>(c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)) << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::hex << (uint8_t)(c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned)(uint8_t)(c) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output seems to be:

```
\ufffd (tries to print it as a char)
b7
\ufffd (tries to print it as a char)
b7
```

I do understand that c has higher bits set (`10110111`), but I cast it to `uint8_t` and `unsigned char` once already.

Why do I have to cast `uint8_t` or `unsigned char` to `unsigned` again to get the expected output?

Comment: `unsigned` means `unsigned int`

Comment: You didn't try not casting at all.

Comment: Perhaps would be better not to use `auto` in this case - be clear on the type

Comment: @Brian: why does not the 8bit unsigned invocation work?

Comment: @PoorLuzer because Unicode.

Comment: @5gon12eder, Ed: This question *is* about understanding types. That's why I explicitly used auto (what does the compiler guess it as?) and did not print out not using casting

Comment: @PoorLuzer The deduced type of `c` is `int`. Maybe you should change your title.  It sounds a lot like you want to get hex output working.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Suggest a title

Comment: @PoorLuzer I would but I'm not sure what question you want to ask.

Comment: Wow, all those calls to `endl`! `std::cout` will most certainly be flushed! (use '\n' when all you need is a new line)

Comment: You assuredly don't need to cast twice.  I note that you never tried casting directly to `unsigned` without going through `unsigned char`.  It seems that your real question is "Why does sending an `unsigned char` to `std::cout` print it as a character?"  Are you really surprised by that?  Which leaves only "Why is `uint8_t` treated as a character?", which is already answered, so I've marked a duplicate.

Comment: _"Why do I have to cast a byte as unsigned twice to see hex output?"_ You don't, and you didn't.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Are you implying the `uint8_t` is treated as `unsigned char` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) sets the [basefield of the stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags) *str* to `hex` as if by calling `str.setf(std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield)`.

> When this basefield `hex` bit is set, `iostream`s use hexadecimal base for **integer** I/O.

#### Code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 0xb7;
    unsigned u = 0xb7;
    char c = static_cast<char>(0xb7);
    unsigned char b = 0xb7;

    std::cout << std::hex << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << u << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
b7
b7
�
�
```

I suspect this output to vary on a Windows (non UTF-8) system.

Comment: So does this mean that unless the type is an `int`, `iostreams` will ignore the `std::hex` modifier and print everything as a raw byte anyways? Even an `uint8_t` which I assumed to be a byte (incorrect assumption?)

Comment: Doesn't have to be `int` in particular, does have to be an integral type that is not a character type. Standard doesn't say if `uint8_t` is a character type - it is allowed to be but not required. On your system it is. See linked question.

Comment: Great answer. Loved the references. I'll email you shortly at the contact info. Would you be able to review some of my unanswered questions? (two of them below)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873356/challenges-in-writing-wrappers-for-c-functions-so-that-they-can-be-used-from-c
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874161/c-tokenizer-and-it-returns-empty-too-when-fields-are-missing-yay