# Avoid linking to libstdc++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, libstdc++

I'm working on an embedded project that currently uses C in Linux and uClibc. We're interested in moving it to C++, but I don't want the overhead associated with linking in libstdc++. My impression is that this is possible provided we don't use anything from STL, such as iostream or vector.

How does one direct g++ to compile without linking to libstdc++?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you compile, use `g++ -c` to compile only.  Then for linking, use `ld` instead of `g++`.  This invokes the linker directly, which requires you to name all your libraries on the command line (including libc and libcrt), however.

Alternatively, if you're using g++ as a "better c", you may be able to use `gcc` for your final link step (which will include libc automatically)

Comment: When I try this I get "undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'" when trying to link.

Comment: I think that means you're using some C++ specific feature.  As to which feature it is, I'm not sure.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work by referring to <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329059/what-is-gxxpersonalityv0-for">this question</a>. You have to compile with "g++ -fno-exceptions -c" and then link separately.

Comment: That link was supposed to be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329059/what-is-gxxpersonalityv0-for

Answer (score 13):

You could use

```
g++ -nodefaultlibs -fno-exceptions a.cc
```

But you cannot use all c++ features this way...

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness and correctness:

```
g++ -c -fno-exceptions a.cpp
gcc a.o -o a
```