# Installing mmh3 package with pip on conda/MacOS

Tags: python, pip, spacy

So I'm trying to setup and install again a package that requires mmh3 on MacOS.

When I get there - I am getting errors that for all intents and purposes might as well be in a different language for me.

Searches thus far have led me to believe it is *something* to do with the version of Apple's xCode I have on my machine, but the answers I have found are completely meaningless. I don't know how to edit the installation files if all I am doing is calling `pip install mmh3`.

The output is as follows, I know it is long - but I don't know what is and isn't relevant, so it's all there. It's somehting to do with APple renaming c++ or something like it. ANy help will be much appreciated. Please keep in mind I have NO idea why this package is required, just that it is.

```
Collecting mmh3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/7e/3ddcab0a9fcea034212c02eb411433db9330e34d626360b97333368b4052/mmh3-2.5.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mmh3
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mmh3 ... error
  Complete output from command /Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/29/638ydzz51zxfm1hht53r24w80000gn/T/pip-install-qieyu8iz/mmh3/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/29/638ydzz51zxfm1hht53r24w80000gn/T/pip-wheel-a0npl5pu --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'mmh3' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/include/python3.7m -c mmh3module.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/mmh3module.o
  warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
  1 warning generated.
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/include/python3.7m -c MurmurHash3.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/MurmurHash3.o
  warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
  1 warning generated.
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7
  g++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/lib -arch x86_64 -L/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/mmh3module.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/MurmurHash3.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/mmh3.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
  ld: library not found for -lstdc++
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mmh3
  Running setup.py clean for mmh3
Failed to build mmh3
Installing collected packages: mmh3
  Running setup.py install for mmh3 ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/29/638ydzz51zxfm1hht53r24w80000gn/T/pip-install-qieyu8iz/mmh3/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/29/638ydzz51zxfm1hht53r24w80000gn/T/pip-record-z9u9z7f5/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'mmh3' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/include/python3.7m -c mmh3module.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/mmh3module.o
    warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/include/python3.7m -c MurmurHash3.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/MurmurHash3.o
    warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
    1 warning generated.
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7
    g++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/lib -arch x86_64 -L/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/mmh3module.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/MurmurHash3.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/mmh3.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
    ld: library not found for -lstdc++
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/ronan/miniconda3/envs/prodigy/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/29/638ydzz51zxfm1hht53r24w80000gn/T/pip-install-qieyu8iz/mmh3/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/29/638ydzz51zxfm1hht53r24w80000gn/T/pip-record-z9u9z7f5/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/29/638ydzz51zxfm1hht53r24w80000gn/T/pip-install-qieyu8iz/mmh3/
```

Comment: I know this has been asked before (probably by myself) with respect to this package. I have now found that it has already been flagged on GitHub with the developers [here](https://github.com/hajimes/mmh3/issues/20), but with no response as yet. If anyone is familiar with building Python Wheels or _exactly where_ the C++ code needs to be updated, help would be again, much appreciated. This is an Apple OS issue, which has led to a number of downstream issues.

As always, @ines or honnibal, your input would be appreciated

Comment: Actually, I've got exactly the same error message when I did "pip install mmh3". Luckily, I succeeded after some tries and errors. 
=> I removed old python version and installed latest python3, virtualenv, pip, etc. The Clang or Xcode things doesn't help me, only clean python installation did help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as always, the answer is incredibly simple after you've seen it.

The solution to this problem as well as any others that are reliant on these C++ libraries being referenced from Python is an if/else block in the `setup.py` file used in implementing the package. The following lines of code included and executed if running on OSX >= 10.7 will resolve this kind of complaint from pip and Python.

```
COMPILE_OPTIONS["other"].append("-stdlib=libc++")
LINK_OPTIONS["other"].append("-lc++")
LINK_OPTIONS["other"].append("-nodefaultlibs")
```

For reference, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653047/avoid-linking-to-libstdc) is some info on the issue's source.

Credit for the solution should go to @honnibal, and the full if/else logic and block is now available via [this link](https://github.com/honnibal/mmh3/commit/8f68a372b13b1c72da4e6a14beb559f21f5f541e), so you can have a squiz to see what's going on.

Comment: I did a git clone and then ran the pip install on the setup.py file. I get this:ld: "library not found for -lstdc++". Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have Apple's development suite installed? So, xCode, and associated libraries? This is where the command line tools are required and the root of this problem to begin with. Look at installing/updating xCode and the command line tools if you haven't already. I'm sorry I'm not able to help more!

Comment: Thanks rtob. I did some more digging but it seems like on OSX 10.7+ those libraries aren't provided any more. I'm still stuck :'(

Comment: G'day @David - Not really sure how best to respond here as I'm no longer using this environment. The lstdc++ libraries *should* be cleanly deprecated? If not, it'll be something small or an if/else block in the setup.py file that needs changing before you build the wheel from it I believe...

Answer (score 1):

I followed the guideline in the link, https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mmh3, and found it works.

To install this package with conda run one of the following:

conda install -c conda-forge mmh3

conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 mmh3

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thanks!