# Failed to install spacy

Tags: python, linux, pip, spacy

I have a problem.
I am trying to install spacy on my linux machine, but it gives me lots of errors with this command:

```
pip3 install spacy
```

This is the output I get when I try to install it:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-srt_eep7 --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --extra-index-url https://www.piwheels.org/simple -- setuptools wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0 Cython cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0 preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0 murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0 thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0" failed with error code 1 in None
```

This is relevant output of all the errors that it gives.
I have no idea what to do, but I need it to work with!?
I am running on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian buster lite.

**UPDATE**
Now I get this message after downloading the source code and pasting your code in the setup.py and then running it with `python /spacy/setup.py`:

```
Cythonizing sources
Processing kb.pyx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.env/bin/cython", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(setuptools_main())
  File "/root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 840, in setuptools_main
    return main(command_line = 1)
  File "/root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 858, in main
    result = compile(sources, options)
  File "/root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 780, in compile
    return compile_multiple(source, options)
  File "/root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 750, in compile_multiple
    context = options.create_context()
  File "/root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 597, in create_context
    self.cplus, self.language_level, options=self)
  File "/root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 80, in __init__
    from . import Builtin, CythonScope
  File "/root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/CythonScope.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .UtilityCode import CythonUtilityCode
  File "/root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/UtilityCode.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .TreeFragment import parse_from_strings, StringParseContext
  File "/root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/TreeFragment.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .Visitor import VisitorTransform
  File "Cython/Compiler/Visitor.py", line 17, in init Cython.Compiler.Visitor
  File "/root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/ExprNodes.py", line 4724, in <module>
    class SliceIndexNode(ExprNode):
  File "/root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/ExprNodes.py", line 4922, in SliceIndexNode
    "SliceObject", "ObjectHandling.c", context={'access': 'Get'})
  File "/root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Code.py", line 404, in load
    return cls(**kwargs)
  File "/root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Code.py", line 648, in __init__
    proto = sub_tempita(proto, context, file, name)
  File "/root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Code.py", line 640, in sub_tempita
    from ..Tempita import sub
  File "/root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Tempita/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._tempita import *
ImportError: /root/.env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Cython/Tempita/_tempita.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/spaCy/bin/cythonize.py", line 169, in <module>
    run(args.root)
  File "/root/spaCy/bin/cythonize.py", line 158, in run
    process(base, filename, db)
  File "/root/spaCy/bin/cythonize.py", line 124, in process
    preserve_cwd(base, process_pyx, root + ".pyx", root + ".cpp")
  File "/root/spaCy/bin/cythonize.py", line 87, in preserve_cwd
    func(*args)
  File "/root/spaCy/bin/cythonize.py", line 63, in process_pyx
    raise Exception("Cython failed")
Exception: Cython failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 278, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 211, in setup_package
    generate_cython(root, "spacy")
  File "setup.py", line 134, in generate_cython
    raise RuntimeError("Running cythonize failed")
RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install gcc python-dev` before run `pip`.

Comment: Are you sure, please post the latest information here

Comment: I will copy/paste the output what I get now!

Comment: Its updated with the last response

Comment: There are prebuilt wheels of `spacy` for Raspbian, but not for all Python versions; which one do you use? You might try running `pip3 install spacy --only-binary=spacy`, if you use Python 3.6 or older, the command should install just fine.

Comment: hi @hoefling after running your command:  ```Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement spacy (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for spacy```

Comment: hi @A.Vreeswijk have you made it?

Comment: @Franva "no matching distributions" means there are no prebuilt wheels for your Python/ABI combination. Run `python -c "from pip._internal.pep425tags import get_supported; print(get_supported()[0])"`, what do you get?

Comment: hi @hoefling ```('cp37', 'cp37m', 'linux_armv7l')``` thanks for your reply. I have been stuck here for the entire day, tried at least 10 approaches to make it work, but still no luck...

Comment: @Franva unfortunately, there are no prebuilt wheels for Python 3.7 on RPi (the platform is ok though). Either switch to Python 3.6 or [install from source](https://spacy.io/usage#source), refer also to the given answer for ARM-specific tweaks.

Comment: hi @hoefling thanks for your tips. I actually have tried to install from source. It throws out the same error.

Comment: hi @hoefling here is the detailed error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927844/is-it-possible-to-install-spacy-to-raspberry-pi-4-raspbian-buster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to compile `spacy` on Rasp. but GCC doesn't support those flags on the ARM platform.

> gcc: note: valid arguments are: armv2 armv2a armv3 armv3m armv4
>   armv4t armv5 armv5t armv5e armv5te armv5tej armv6 armv6j armv6k armv6z
>   armv6kz armv6zk armv6t2 armv6-m armv6s-m armv7 armv7-a armv7ve armv7-r
>   armv7-m armv7e-m armv8-a armv8.1-a armv8.2-a armv8.3-a armv8.4-a
>   armv8-m.base armv8-m.main armv8-r iwmmxt iwmmxt2 native
>       gcc: error: missing argument to ‘-march=’
>       gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mavx2’
>       gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfma’
>       gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfpmath=sse’

So, to make it work on your platform, I suggest you run configure with the option --disable-sse2. it means you can download the `spacy` source code and then modify or configure its Makefile by yourself. and then try `python setup.py install`.

You may need to know about this [setup.py](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/setup.py) and [Makefile](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/Makefile)

To change `setup.py` to suit your platform, you can modify [some code](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/setup.py#L79), for example:

```
if is_new_osx():
    # On Mac, use libc++ because Apple deprecated use of
    # libstdc
    COMPILE_OPTIONS["other"].append("-stdlib=libc++")
    LINK_OPTIONS["other"].append("-lc++")
    # g++ (used by unix compiler on mac) links to libstdc++ as a default lib.
    # See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653047/avoid-linking-to-libstdc
    LINK_OPTIONS["other"].append("-nodefaultlibs")
    # Because I am running it on my Rasp Pi
    # I want to remove some options from LINK_OPTIONS or Add some into it
```

Comment: What do I need to configure in the Makefile?

Comment: I have added an Update to my question with the next error :(

Comment: And you said: "To change setup.py to suit your platform, you can modify some code", but how can I know if it suits my platform?

Comment: hi @FrankAK could you please help? I'm on Raspbian Buster. Is it possible to do the similar trick here? I've had a look and cannot find anything to change. please help, thanks

Comment: @Franva Well, it depends, could you post your question on SO?

Comment: thanks @FrankAK I have got my answer from there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927844/is-it-possible-to-install-spacy-to-raspberry-pi-4-raspbian-buster/59957172?noredirect=1#comment106081791_59957172