# c ,c++ file extension problem

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I write a program in c++ on ubuntu (10.04)and saved it as.cc file when i complile

it wit g++ cat.cc it work fine . There is no problem the code is working fine.

but when i compile it with gcc than it show me an error which is following :/tmp/cc8aU82C.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

my code is following :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct man
{
    int a ;
    int b;
    void show(int x,int y);
}
};

int main()
{
    man m; 
    int c=50;
    int d;
    m.show(c,d);
    return 0;
}

void man::show(int x,int y)
{
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

Now can anybody tell me what happens wrong when i compile it with gcc?

What is the exact difference between .cpp and .cc extension if they are same than why we use them ? why do  they exist ?

Comment: There is an error in your code I believe an extra }; after the structure ends..please check it

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is __gxx_personality_v0 for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329059/what-is-gxx-personality-v0-for)

Answer (score 4):

If you compile with gcc, the C++ runtime is not linked in by default, so you will get linker errors like the one you are seeing. gcc and g++ will both compile files with the .cpp and .cc extensions (and others which I have forgotten) as C++, and those with a .c extension as C. But its better to be explicit and use g++ fror your C++ code and gcc for C.

Comment: Either use `g++` or `gcc -lstdc++`.

Comment: IIRC, g++ will compile files with a `.c` as C++.  Practically speaking, you should compile files ending in `.c` with `gcc`, files ending in `.cpp`, `.cc` or `.C` with `g++` (although `gcc` will also work); when linking, if there are any C++ sources in the files to be linked, use `g++`.

Answer (score 0):

gcc is C compiler not C++ compiler, g++ is the C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

They exist because some people have used them. :-)

When you compile with g++ you say that you want to compile the code as C++. Then the extension doesn't matter.