# undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0' with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is __gxx_personality_v0 for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329059/what-is-gxx-personality-v0-for)

I've seen this question circulating around here in the context of compiling C++ code. However I am to compile a *pure* C code and keep on getting this error. I am forbidden to use "-lstdc++" as a workaround to this gcc problem. How to change my code to get it working and why is this error popping out?

My simplified code:

```
//this is main.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch[3];
    ch[0] = getc(stdin);
    ch[1] = getc(stdin);
    ch[2] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", ch);
    return 0;
}
```

My compile command is:

```
gcc main.cpp
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use either `g++` - since your file is suffixed `.cpp` or rename the file to `.c` and keep the command line as is. Tested on Debian 6.0.5 with `gcc` 4.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

man gcc says:

> C++ source files conventionally use one of the suffixes .C, .cc, .cpp, .CPP, .c++, .cp,
>       or .cxx; C++ header files often use .hh, .hpp, .H, or (for shared template code) .tcc;
>       and preprocessed C++ files use the suffix .ii. GCC recognizes files with these names and 
>       compiles them as C++ programs even if you call the compiler the same way as for 
>       compiling C programs (usually with the name gcc).