# The procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, codeblocks, libstdc++

I got that error when trying to run my opencv application. I´m using Windows7,CodeBlocks 12.11, opencv2.4.4 and MinGW compiler (the one that comes in CodeBlocks). It compiles and creates the executable but when i try to run it crashes with the procedure entry point error.
I have added C:\programs\CodeBlocks\Mingw\bin to "PATH" variable and i know there is libstdc++-6.dll.

I don´t know what´s hapenning.

This is the simple code:

```
include <iostream>
include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
namedWindow("window");
Mat image=imread("mustang.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
imshow("window",image);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the procedure entry point \_\_gxx\_personality\_v0 could not be located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668003/the-procedure-entry-point-gxx-personality-v0-could-not-be-located)

Answer (score 3):

The libstdc++-6.dll contains the *runtime* environment. It is an implementation of fundamental routines, such as the heap manager or the exception handling.

These fundamental routines are used in nearly every program. Thus, it would be a waste of memory to put a copy of them into every program. That is why they are usually packed into a shared library (DLL). The programs can then request the DLL when they need the routines of the runtime.

In your case, the libstdc++-6.dll contains a wrong version of the runtime. There are two possibilities:

- Find a libstdc++-6.dll that contains the correct version of the runtime and copy it into the directory of your executable. You can determine whether a DLL is the correct one by running `nm libstdc++-6.dll | grep personality`. If the `__gxx_personality_v0` shows up in the list, then you probably have the correct DLL.
- Put a copy of the runtime environment into the executable. You can do this by adding `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` to your linker parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to have been answered several times here on stackoverflow.
[What is __gxx_personality_v0 for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329059/what-is-gxx-personality-v0-for) as one of them