# Return Pointers With Multiple Value Win32 Linking Error

Tags: c++, pointers, g++, iostream, msys

I have encountered the typical `No Entry Point Personality V0` error before and worked around it with: `-fno-exceptions`. Although this time when I use the workaround cmd crashed and only runs the first `cin >> line` of the program.

However, I can run the program no problem in MSYS.

I compiled with:

> `g++ ReturnPointer.cpp -o ReturnPointer.exe (gave error)`
>
> `g++ ReturnPointer.cpp -o ReturnPointer.exe -fno-exceptions (runs: MSYS Shell Only)`

---

```
    #include <iostream> 

short factor(int, int*, int*);

int main()
{
    int number, squared, cubed;
    short error;

    std::cout << "Enter a number (0 - 20 ): ";
    std::cin >> number;

    error = factor(number, &squared, &cubed);

    if (!error)
    {
        std::cout << "number: " << number << "\n";
        std::cout << "square: " << squared << "\n";
        std::cout << "cubed: " << cubed << "\n";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Error encountered!!\n";

    return 0;
}

short factor(int n, int* pSquared, int* pCubed)
{
    short value = 0;
    if (n > 20)
    {
        value = 1;
    }
    else
    {
            *pSquared = n * n;
            *pCubed   = n * n * n;
        value = 0;
    }
    return value;
}
```

---

Granted, this isn't the end of the world. I am just expanding my knowledge on an area of C++ that trips me up a lot. Although, if I were to ever use pointers in this manner in a larger program...that would turn into a mess.

I would just like to know what needs to be done or what I am missing to run this in CMD.

Comment: Works perfectly fine on my side, `g++4.9` `OS X 10.9.2`. No warnings (`-Wall, -Wextra, -pedantic`)

Comment: The program looks OK to me, this must be a problem with your compiler installation

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668003/the-procedure-entry-point-gxx-personality-v0-could-not-be-located-in-the-dnyam) is the problem?

Comment: Hrmmm, it must be at this point. Just short of a re-install, I can't figure it out. I'll try a new virtual machine. This is weird.

Comment: Thank You @Matt McNabb! That Solved It! I am new to StackOverflow! Is there a point system to reward solutions?

Re: Needed libstdc++-6.dll

Comment: @Proteu5 normally yes, however instead of me repeating the answer on the linked thread , this question should just be linked to that thread

Comment: Ahh Okay, Thanks! I am learning.