# The procedure entry point could not be located

Tags: c++, dll, g++, mingw, stdstring

I'm trying to compile a C++ program with MinGW on Windows 10, but I keep receiving the following error (-Wall and -Werror are activated):

> The procedure entry point
>
> _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEEC1EPKcRKS3_
>
> could not be loaded in the dynamic link library
>
> [path to executable].exe

The other solutions I found for something like that referenced an external DLL, not the executable itself.

I'm a C# guy, and this is all foreign to me, so pardon me if it's a really simple linking error or something like that.

Everything is in one file (since it's going to be graded by an online automated judge):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum Months { January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December };

std::string monthNames[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
int monthLengths[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]);
bool isLeapYear(int year);
int daysInMonth(Months month, int year);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Leap years:" << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(monthNames)/sizeof(*monthNames); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << monthNames[i] << ": " << daysInMonth(static_cast<Months>(i), 2000) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Non-leap years:" << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(monthNames)/sizeof(*monthNames); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << monthNames[i] << ": " << daysInMonth(static_cast<Months>(i), 1999) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}

bool isLeapYear(int year)
{
    return ((year & 3) == 0 && ((year % 25) != 0 || (year & 15) == 0));
}

int daysInMonth(Months month, int year)
{
    if (isLeapYear(year) && month == February)
    {
        return 29;
    }

    return monthLengths[month];
}
```

Comment: `#include <string>`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Duly noted, but it's still happening.

Comment: Oh. I voted to close it. But I don't know how to remove that vote. OK, I'll try to reproduce. Which distribution of MinGW are you using, which version, and what is your build command?

Comment: Can you please show the command you use, complete with all flags? Also what version of GCC are you using (get it with `gcc --version`)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Refer to my answer below.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668003/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually just a problem with my MinGW installation (I used a version of g++ somewhere else, and it worked like a charm).

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the string header to use string.

```cpp
#include <string>
```

Comment: Edited. Still having the same problem, though.