# Getting __gxx_personality_v0 error after compiling C++ with g++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, g++, mingw

Title.

After successfully compiling this program:

```
#include <iostream>

class test
{
    public:
    int Render() {return 4;}
};

int main()
{
    test b;
    std::cout << b.Render() << std::endl;   
    return 0;
}
```

With this command:

```
g++ .\src\test.cpp -lstdc++
```

The executable produced produces error message (paraphrased as I'm translating):

```
Entry point for procedure __gxx_personality_v0 in library [path of executable] not found.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe adding -lgcc_s will help?

Comment: @nsilent22 Nope, didn't help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668003/the-procedure-entry-point-gxx-personality-v0-could-not-be-located-in-the-dnyam ?

Comment: Oh boy, that worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Copy libstdc++6.dll from C:\mingw\bin into the executable's folder.