# g++ compiles c++ script with #include-statements to .exe-file which fails to run

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I have the following script in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <string> markus = { "M", "A", "R", "K", "U", "S" };
    for (int i = 0; i < markus.size();i++) {
        cout << markus[i];
     }

     return 0;
}
```

I have successfully installed g++. When I try compiling this code with the command `g++ -o test test.cpp`, I get no errors. However, when I try running the created `test.exe`-file, with the command `test`, I get an error saying "could not find starting point". First, there is a long sequence, then the following message; "The starting point for the procedure could not be found in the library for dynamical links", and the the absolute path for `test.exe`.

If I remove `#include <vector>`, and try the following code;

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout  << "Hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

, it works perfect.

I would be glad for the help.

Comment: Have you tried `#include <string>`? Not sure if it's related.

Comment: Calling your executable `test` is begging for confusion with the shell built-in `test` command.

Comment: @Steve, when I try it in other online compilators it seem to work without the #include <string>-statement. Like my code in the OP.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth - that may be a dumb thing to do, yes. But the program, which had no problem running, had the same name; "test".

Comment: iostream often includes string, but one shouldn't count on it. Since you are successfully compiling, this isn't your problem. Unable to reproduce.

Comment: It seems somewhat unlikely that the code itself would cause this issue, so make sure, that the code is really the only difference between the two builds. If you're sure, try to narrow down what exactly causes the problem: Start with the second version and transform it step by step into the first version (e.g. include <vector>, but don't use it at first, etc.) until it breaks.

Comment: Try to compile without using namespace std; do std::cout instead

Comment: Could you add the error message as text.   It may be an issue with the command line for compiling/running the app, or the compiler installation

Comment: The first answer in this post fixed my problem; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668003/the-procedure-entry-point-gxx-personality-v0-could-not-be-located