# C++ "Entry Point Not Found" when trying to write to file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write to a file in C++, however as soon as I run my .exe file, I get the following error

"`The procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library C:/Users...`"

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ofstream outfile ("test.txt");
    outfile << "Hello World\n"; // error happens here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `const` from the function declaration.

Comment: `int main(int argc, char const *argv[])` is not an approved signature for `main`. Remove the `const`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but error still persists

Comment: I should mention my file extension is .cpp (if that makes any difference)

Comment: Possibly the same issue as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668003/the-procedure-entry-point-gxx-personality-v0-could-not-be-located#20455257 ?

Comment: The error you are receiving has absolutely nothing to do with "trying to write to file".  It has to do with how you compile and link your `.exe`.  Please show the name of the dynamic link library, as well as the commands you use to compile and link, compiler options, linker options, etc.

Comment: @MikeNakis I'm not sure how to exactly see "name of dynamic link library" or what it is but this is the command I'm using... 

g++ -o dbug dbug.cpp

Comment: run ldd on your  output file, make sure it's linked with libstdc++

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem by copying libstdc++-6.dll from  `C:\MinGW\bin` into the directory of my project!

Comment: The alternative (and perhaps better way) would be to have added `C:\MinGW\bin` to your `PATH`.

Comment: You should also look at "dynamic link library C:/Users...". It could be a different installation of a different version of gcc. If so, remove it, or at least remove it from your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream.h>
int main()
{
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("text.txt")//opening the file
outfile<<"Hello world";
outfile.close();//closing the file
return 0;
}
```

whenever we are dealing with files, there should be opening the file and closing the file. For this program , the arguments inside the main function is not needed.