# Exit code 3221225785 when I try to run any code with strings

Tags: c++, string

I keep getting an error when I try to run any code with strings. When I tried running it through CMD, it gave an error window saying

> The procedure entry point _ZNKSt7_cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEE6substrEjj could not be located in the dynamic library (code file directory)".

Here's the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    int main()
    {
        std::string line1 = "Hello";
        std::cout << line1 << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: What command are you using to execute the code?

Comment: You should put `return 0;` right behind `std::cout << line1 << std::endl;`.

Comment: `3 221 225 785` in hex is `0xC0000139` I now think your problem is a mismatched runtime. Meaning you probably have an older version of your compiler's runtime in one of the folders listed in your windows `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: You get a similar error when you compile C++ with `clang` instead of `clang++` because the C++ standard library isn't linked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47295060/1505939

Comment: Did it actually say "[...] located in the dynamic library (code file directory)" or is that your editing? It would be better to post the exact message

Comment: The "code file directory" is my editing, but I found a solution using the links above. Thanks.