# How can I link C++ files to a C program?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, g++

I'm currently trying to link a big C++ program to a C "wrapper," to allow integration with a program in another language whose compiler understands C but not C++ (Haskell GHC, to be precise.)  But my attempts to do so, either with GHC or GCC, meet strange problems.

To model the situation concisely, say I have a main program file in C:

cmain.c

```
#include "header.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  printf("%d\n", cppfun(12));

  return 0;
}
```

and a helper function defined in a .cpp file:

cppmodule.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#include "further.h"

class foobar {
public:
  int getfive () {return 5;}
};

extern "C" { 
int cppfun(int foo) {
  foobar fb;

  return fb.getfive();
}
}
```

This much will compile just fine.  But if, instead, cppmodule.cpp refers to a further .cpp file, like so:

cppmodule.cpp mk II

```
#include "header.h"
#include "further.h"

class foobar {
public:
  int getfive () {return 5;}
};

extern "C" { 
int cppfun(int foo) {
  foobar fb;

  return fb.getfive() + morecpp();
}
}
```

where the new .cpp file is something similar;

```
morecpp.cpp

#include "further.h"

class moreobjects {
public:
  int getsix() {return 6;}
};


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


int morecpp() {
  moreobjects mo;

  return mo.getsix();
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I suddenly get an error when I'm trying to compile with a command like "gcc cmain.o cppmodule.o morecpp.o"; compiling with g++ works but, as I mentioned, this kind of solution doesn't fit my purposes.

The error I get trying to compile this example is

```
max@SoutheastCorner:~/Projectsync/maketest$ gcc cmain.o cppmodule.o morecpp.o
cppmodule.o:(.eh_frame+0x4b): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The same kind of attempt with my actual project code additionally gives screenfulls of errors of the form

```
hopnode.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt10_List_nodeI4nodeIPcS3_EEE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt10_List_nodeI4nodeIPcS3_EEE8allocateEmPKv]+0x4d): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/tmp/ccaoEEFM.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<char* const, node<char*, char*> > > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':
hopnode.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt13_Rb_tree_nodeISt4pairIKPc4nodeIS3_S3_EEEE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt13_Rb_tree_nodeISt4pairIKPc4nodeIS3_S3_EEEE8allocateEmPKv]+0x2c): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
hopnode.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt13_Rb_tree_nodeISt4pairIKPc4nodeIS3_S3_EEEE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt13_Rb_tree_nodeISt4pairIKPc4nodeIS3_S3_EEEE8allocateEmPKv]+0x46): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is \_\_gxx\_personality\_v0 for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329059/what-is-gxx-personality-v0-for)

Comment: I'd seen that question, but if an answer to my problem is contained within I've failed to understand it.

Comment: There are lots of duplicates, but perhaps I haven't picked the best one.  Anyway, the solution is in the first answer at the question I linked; either link with G++, or add `-lstdc++`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is at the link stage.  Your program is missing the symbols from the C++ standard library.  To fix this, you have to either link with the g++ driver or you have to explicitly link in the C++ standard library.

Linking with g++ is the easiest solution, but you can also try adding `-lstdc++` as a library flag.

Keep in mind that there are still a lot of pitfalls associated with this.  The C++ ABI is not simple, and is not necessarily consistent across compilers (clang/g++/etc.) or even different versions of GCC.  This can be a problem if your Haskell program dynamically links to other C++ code compiled with a different C++ ABI.

Also note that you also **must** catch all exceptions at the C/C++ boundary.  Haskell expects a straight C ABI and cannot deal with C++ exceptions that leak through the C/C++ boundary.

Comment: I tried linking with g++, and got the same result.  But giving -lstdc++ to GHC works, which I hadn't thought of.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have C++ code in C code, use `extern "C++"` around all the C++ code which your C program uses. Then you can compile it as a C program and Haskell wouldn't even know that it's implemented using some C++ code behind the scenes.

EDIT: I never tried this direction (usually you use C code in a C++ project), but basically this is how it's supposed to work.

If it doesn't just work, try compiling the C++ program like any normal C++ program with g++, then write a C program which uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding extern "C" to c++ functions that will be called in C. The C++ compiler must know that the function is to be called by a C compiler using the extern "C" construct.

// In your C++ code

// Declare function(char, int) as a c function using extern "C":
extern "C" void function(char c, int i);

...

// Implement function(char,int) in C++ module:
void function(char c, int i)
{
  ...
}