# SFML projects won't run after updating MinGW from 4.4.1 to 4.7.1

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, codeblocks, sfml

So this morning I upgraded my MinGW compiler to 4.7.1 (from 4.4.1, I believe), and have since been trying to get old projects building and running properly again.  My efforts have met a wall, however, in that now, whenever I try to compile projects that use the SFML library, I get the following error:

**The procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll**

Now I know this problem [has been discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329059/what-is-gxx-personality-v0-for), but unfortunately the proposed hacky-fix of defining `void *__gxx_personality_v0;` hasn't done me any good, and I've checked whether I am accidentally using GCC, but CodeBlocks has the C++ compiler set to MinGW's G++, not GCC (under Settings->Compiler->Toolchain Executables->Program Files, I have `mingw32-g++.exe` as the C++ compiler).  So that doesn't seem to be the problem.

The program I am trying to compile, in its entirety, is an [example from the SFML website](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-cb.php):

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Right now this issue occurs with every single SFML project I try to run, but small non-SFML projects seem to run fine.

What could I try in order to fix this?

Comment: I just post an answer, but in order to really find the problem, it would be interesting to see your project directory structure and the files each dir contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would need some more information, but let me try to guess here. Would it be possible that somehow, you're still linking the old (or another version) of the `libstdc++-6.dll` file?

Are the dll beside your EXE? Have you tried taking the version provided by the compiler you're using? In that case MinGW in which the libstdc++-6.dll file is under the bin directory.

Comment: I actually managed to solve the problem by essentially uninstalling my compiler/IDE/libraries and reinstalling them. I still don't know what exactly happened or why it wasn't working. The DLLs were in fact next alongside the EXE as they should be; I think the problem might have had something to do with a confusion between the DW2 and SJLJ versions of SFML and MinGW, even though I thought I had compatible versions thereof.