# Error dynamic link library in Firefox /bin/sh: symbol lookup error

Tags: linux, firefox, gcc, dll, shared-libraries

I'm trying to load a library to Firefox, and I get the following error in the terminal:

http://pastebin.com/ZLryd20D,

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c 11.cpp ,

gcc -shared  -o libshared.so 11.o -ldl ,

LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/libshared.so firefox ,
```

> /bin/sh: symbol lookup error: /home/enigma/Desktop/compilacionproceso/libshared.so: undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `gcc -shared -o libshared.so 11.o -ldl -lstdc++`

That's the wrong solution, that happens to work on Linux by accident.
The correct command line to build your shared library is:

```
g++ -shared -o libshared.so 11.o
```

(contrary to popular belief, `gcc` and `g++` are not the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the OP himself, taken from a revision of the question:

> I solved the problem adding a flag  -lstdc++ for create the library
>   thanks to this post
>   [What is __gxx_personality_v0 for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329059/what-is-gxx-personality-v0-for)
>
> ```
> cd  /directory
>
> gcc -Wall -fPIC -c 11.cpp 
>
> gcc -shared  -o libshared.so 11.o -ldl -lstdc++
>
> LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/libshared.so program
> ```