# How to pass rustc flags to cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to disable dead code warnings. I tried the following

```
cargo build -- -A dead_code
```

> ➜  rla git:(master) ✗ cargo build -- -A dead_code
>   error: Invalid arguments.

So I am wondering how would I pass rustc arguments to cargo?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can pass flags through Cargo by several different means:

- `cargo rustc`, which only affects your crate and not its dependencies.
- The [`RUSTFLAGS`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html) environment variable, which affects dependencies as well.
- Some flags have a proper Cargo option, e.g., `-C lto` and `-C panic=abort` can be specified in the `Cargo.toml` file.
- Add flags in [`.cargo/config`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) using one of the `rustflags=` keys.

---

However, in your specific case of configuring lints, you don't need to use compiler flags; you can also enable and disable lints directly in the source code using attributes. This may in fact be a better option as it's more robust, more targeted, and doesn't require you to alter your build system setup:

```
#![deny(some_lint)] // deny lint in this module and its children

#[allow(another_lint)] // allow lint in this function
fn foo() {
    ...
}
```

See also:

- [How to disable unused code warnings in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25877285/155423)

Comment: E.g. In bash,  `RUSTFLAGS="-C opt-level=3 -C debuginfo=0" cargo build --release` will build an optimized (for speed) release build stripped of debug symbols (for size).

Comment: Does not work.  Still contains hardcoded pathnames in debug information in the executable; e.g. `a Display implementation returned an error unexpectedly C:\\Users\\...`

Comment: @GirkovArpa see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54842093/1541330 for how to fully minimize the size of a Rust executable.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable dead code warnings by modifying config.toml file.
if file doesn't exists create one as below locations.

```
Windows: %USERPROFILE%\.cargo\config.toml
Unix: $HOME/.cargo/config.toml
```

Then add below line

```
[target.'cfg(target_family = "windows")']
rustflags = ["-Adead_code"]
```

If you dont want to see any unused variable warnings add below line

```
[target.'cfg(target_family = "windows")']
rustflags = ["-Aunused"]
```

Don't forget to disable these before Production :)