# Does rustc / cargo have a -march=native equivalent?

Tags: optimization, rust, cpu-architecture, compiler-optimization, rust-cargo

I feel like binary portability isn't really a concern, and so something like -march=native may always be the default behavior.  I can't find anything saying one way or the other though.

Comment: `rustc -C target-cpu=native ...`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, pass the `-C target-cpu` option to rustc:

```
rustc -C target-cpu=native
```

For more options:

```
$ rustc -C help
    ...     
    -C        target-cpu=val -- select target processor (rustc --print target-cpus for details)
    ...
```

See [How to pass rustc flags to cargo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38040327/155423) for more methods of passing the option.

> I feel like binary portability isn't really a concern

I'm pretty sure that the Firefox developers that rely on Rust would disagree with you, as well as plenty of others.

Comment: That's absolutely true...  I knew I was missing something.  I was thinking that crates are installed locally through cargo install - which compiles from source.  Dependencies are also source-based.  Thanks!