# How to specify the output file name of a library via the command line?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How to specify an output file name dynamically via a command line for a library?

```
# something like this
cargo build --output-file-name "my_lib.so" # or .*dylib
```

Doing it via Cargo.toml or .cargo/config won't work for me.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: Rename the file after building? You probably can make something work with `cargo rustc` or `RUSTFLAGS`, but I'm not sure it's worth it.

Answer (score 5):

*Edit:*

See the following: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#configuring-a-target which might help you specify the name of the final `.so`

---

The following parameter controls the output file name in `rustc`

https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/command-line-arguments.html#-o-filename-of-the-output

As [Steve Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach) mentioned you can pass flags to `rustc` through several ways described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040327/how-to-pass-rustc-flags-to-cargo).

Alternatively you could have a post-build script using [Philipp Oppermann's cargo-post](https://github.com/phil-opp/cargo-post) tool and set it up to rename the output lib.