# How do I compile Rust code without linking, i.e. produce object files?

Tags: rust

Due to [how the LGPL works](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#LGPLStaticVsDynamic), compiling Rust code to an object file without linking would be useful to be able to do. However, I cannot find any documentation on how to do this. I checked rustc's help section and searched, but couldn't find anything, which brings me to my question: How do I tell rustc to not link and produce object files that later can be linked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the compiler flag `--emit=obj`.

```
cargo rustc -- --emit=obj
```

The compiled object files will be sitting in `target/debug/deps`.

See also:

- [How to pass rustc flags to cargo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040327/how-to-pass-rustc-flags-to-cargo)

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work. I get a `warning: ignoring emit path because multiple .o files were produced` logged when running the command and `ls target/debug/deps | egrep '\.o'` yields nothing. Also looking at the results I get from `ls target/debug/deps` I don't see any .o files.

Comment: That is project dependent, @Newbyte. You may need to specify a single target crate at a time (e.g. only lib).

Comment: Would it be reasonable to add an example of how you'd go about doing that to the answer? I don't think I'm familiar enough with cargo and rustc to know how to do that, and I would think it's at the very least indirectly relevant to the question.