# Change compiler options based on the selected features

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is it possible to set a certain compiler switch if a feature is enabled? For example I would like to add a feature *instrument* and compile everything with `-Z instrument-mcount`. I did take a look at the options available for `.cargo/config.toml` but could not find anything useful.

Comment: The question cant be answered properly, as not all `rustc` flags are exposed via cargo. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38040431/9306292), what is available.

Comment: What do you mean with it cannot be answered properly? It is not possible at the moment would be a proper answer.

Comment: The flag `-Z` defines unstable compiler options, which are not exposed via cargo.

Comment: Look here for a build.rs from [rftrace](https://github.com/tlambertz/rftrace/blob/master/rftrace/build.rs).