# How to disable unused variable warning in Rust?

Tags: rust

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877389/10116440), `#[allow(dead_code)]` should work, but it doesn't

```
fn main() {
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    let x = 0;
}
```

Comment: The best way would be to remove the unused code. Maybe you'd be better off explaining why that approach is one you're avoiding, someone might be able to give you a better solution.

Comment: For machine disabling you can look to my answer at below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71119013/10943567

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct is

```
fn main() {
    #[allow(unused_variables)]
    let x = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

These are different lints. `dead_code` refers to unused code at the item level, e.g. imports, functions and types. `unused_variables` refers to variables that are never accessed.

You can also cover both cases with `#[allow(unused)]`.

Comment: Also, prefixing the variable name with an underscore suppresses the warning: `let _x = 0;`

Answer (score 12):

Put `#![allow(unused)]` at the top of the file (note the !).

Comment: Thanks for specifying that it has to be at the top of the file.