# When to use rustc rather than cargo command in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to learn Rust programming language. I see that majority of the time one is working with `cargo` command, e.g. `cargo new`, `cargo add`, `cargo build`, `cargo run` etc. When is `rustc` command used instead of `cargo`?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040327/how-to-pass-rustc-flags-to-cargo

Answer (score 5):

Pretty much never.

Cargo handles a lot of the intricacies of building a Rust project for you, and you pretty much never have to leave it for "standard" development. The only reason not to use it is if you're forced to, like needing to use obscure options, outputting a different format like MIR, of if you need to use a different build system for whatever reason.

Comment: Even in the cases you mentioned `cargo rustc` or `cargo build` with setting `RUSTFLAGS`.

Comment: But `rustc` is sometimes used directly for custom build systems.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to custom or third party build system, there is about 2 scenarios where I would use `rustc` over `cargo`

1. I don't have a full blown cargo project because I'm compiling a single file toy code example with no dependencies other than `std`
2. I want the extended information for an error message `rustc --explain Exxxx`

In all other cases just use `cargo` it's built for handling all the dependency, file & folder layout, consistent configuration, etc. cases