# Is it possible to have crate-specific rustc Zlocation-detail settings?

Tags: rust

I am working in embedded Rust so binary size is extremely limited. Using full [`location_detail`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/compiler-flags/location-detail.html) takes up too much space, but being able to see the cause of panics is very helpful for development.

Ideally, I would like to use `location-detail=none` for all my dependencies but `location-detail=file,line` for the main crate I am building.

Is there any way to achieve this? Is it possible to use different `RUSTFLAGS` for different crates?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38040431/392025), you should be able to pass flags only for the current crate and not its dependencies with a `cargo rustc` command. Maybe something like: `RUSTFLAGS="-Z location-detail=none" cargo rustc -Z location-detail=file,line` ?