# Where are the shared and static libraries of the Rust standard library?

Tags: rust, dynamic-linking

I am trying to compile my Rust project with dynamic linking to reduce the size and provide .so (or .dll on Windows) files with the application just like Qt does for Android. I read [Why are Rust executables so huge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008127/why-are-rust-executables-so-huge) and compiled with

```
cargo rustc  -- -C prefer-dynamic
```

When I run my program, I get this error:

```
 % target/debug/t_pro 
target/debug/t_pro: error while loading shared libraries: libstd-a021829e87e39dcf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please provide additional information: what program are you trying to build? Which compiler version, which toolchain, and which host OS?

Comment: Most operating systems come with tools to search the hard drive for files of a specific name. Have you tried one of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The libraries are installed wherever **you** chose to install Rust. I use [rustup](https://rustup.rs/) on macOS, so they are installed in `~/.rustup/toolchains/*whatever*/lib/` for me.

Use your operating system's tools to search for files of a specific name.

See also:

- [How to set the environmental variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13428910/155423)

Answer (score 9):

I got an [answer on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/9zgmv1/where_are_soa_file_of_rust/).

```
rustc --print=sysroot
```

In my case, the .so files are in `/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib` and .rlib are in `/home/username/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib`.

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH+=:$(rustc --print=sysroot)/lib` worked perfect for me

Comment: I'm on mac, so I had to use DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:$(rustc --print=sysroot)/lib"