# Why doesn't a structure definition copied from winapi into my code have the same behavior?

Tags: winapi, rust

I'm trying to read the `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` of a module using the [definition of that structure](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.8/winapi/um/winnt/struct.IMAGE_DOS_HEADER.html) from the `winapi` crate.

Here is my working code:

```
let mut IDH: IMAGE_DOS_HEADER = uninitialized();
copy_nonoverlapping(library, (&mut IDH as *mut IMAGE_DOS_HEADER) as *mut c_void, size_of::<IMAGE_DOS_HEADER>());
```

I realised that `winapi` was too huge and I wanted my binary file to be less than a megabyte, so I declared the `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` structure by myself:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER{
    pub e_magic: u16,
    pub e_cblp: u16,
    pub e_cp: u16,
    pub e_crlc: u16,
    pub e_cparhdr: u16,
    pub e_minalloc: u16,
    pub e_maxalloc: u16,
    pub e_ss: u16,
    pub e_sp: u16,
    pub e_csum: u16,
    pub e_ip: u16,
    pub e_cs: u16,
    pub e_lfarlc: u16,
    pub e_ovno: u16,
    pub e_res: [u16; 4],
    pub e_oemid: u16,
    pub e_oeminfo: u16,
    pub e_res2: [u16; 10],
    pub e_lfanew: i32,
}
```

When I did that, all of the fields of the structure get weird values (ex: `e_magic = 0x3`).

I decided to convert the structure to an array in both cases, even if they are programmatically exactly the same.

```
println!("{:?}", std::mem::transmute::<IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, [u8;0x40]>(IDH).to_vec());
```

For both of them it printed:

```
[77, 90, 144, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 184, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 232, 0, 0, 0]
```

That's really weird. There shouldn't be any differences between the values of their fields. Then I copied the printed array and converted it to my structure and see if all the fields are ok.

```
let dos: [u8;0x40] = [77, 90, 144, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 184, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 232, 0, 0, 0];
println!("{}", std::mem::transmute::<[u8;0x40], _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER>(dos).e_magic);
```

The first field is equal to `3`.  I have two structures, with the same fields and the exact same size (I verified), I take an array, I convert it to those structures, and I get different fields.

As you can see there's a `3` in the array dump, but it shouldn't be associated with the first field of the structure (`e_magic`), it makes no sense, why would it work with the other one?

I guess I'm missing something when I'm initializing the structure, but what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **didn't** copy the same definition, you copied the part that is shown in the documentation. This is the (truncated) [actual definition](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs/blob/77426a9776f4328d2842175038327c586d5111fd/src/um/winnt.rs#L5508-L5528):

```
STRUCT!{struct IMAGE_DOS_HEADER {
    e_magic: WORD,
    e_cblp: WORD,
    // ...
    e_res2: [WORD; 10],
    e_lfanew: LONG,
}}
```

Notably, this uses the [`STRUCT` macro](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs/blob/77426a9776f4328d2842175038327c586d5111fd/src/macros.rs#L381-L403), which defines a few traits, but more importantly marks the type as `repr(C)`:

```
#[repr(C)] #[derive(Copy)] $(#[$attrs])*
pub struct $name {
    $(pub $field: $ftype,)+
}
```

The layout of Rust structs is not specified, so your structure has some other ordering and padding compared to the C structure, and will not work.

---

> I realised that winapi was too huge and I wanted my binary file to be less than a megabyte, so I declared the IMAGE_DOS_HEADER structure by myself

This is incorrect reasoning. Code from libraries that isn't used is removed from the final binary.

See also:

- [Why are Rust executables so huge?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29008127/155423)

Comment: I tought it was because of the winapi but it was because of a huge buffer I forgot to delete. Thanks it works fine now.