# How to optimize the size of the executable binary file for native and WASM toolchains?

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and so far I was amazed by its design.  But I encountered something that makes me be scared to use it in commercial projects. The size of the executable binary file of a "Hello world" application is 3.2Mb.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 2 kos kos 3,2M Jul 10 15:44 experiment_app_size
```

That's huge!

- The version of `rustc` is `1.53.0`
- The toolchain is `stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.
- Target is `release`.

I am wondering is it planned to fix the problem in the future?
Is there a technique I can use to decrease the size of the executable binary file?
Is the same problem relevant to WASM toolchain?

Comment: This has been frequently discussed, on this site and elsewhere. Start with [Why are Rust executables so huge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008127/why-are-rust-executables-so-huge) and try some basic web searches like "rust binary size".

Comment: @IMSoP 6 years old. Is that still relevant?

Comment: I have no idea, but your question as written shows no evidence of even trying to find existing information.

Comment: @IMSoP It's indeed outdated and has no answer regarding the WASM toolchain. There is not much information about size optimization in official documentation, but the article I shared was recommended to me is good. I need to find an answer regarding the WASM toolchain. The post you refer to does not cover the WASM.

Comment: In that case, you should either: add an answer to the existing question; or ask a question focussing specifically on the WASM toolchain. As currently worded, this question is asking exactly the same thing as the existing one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Rust optimizes for execution speed rather than binary size, since for the vast majority of applications this is ideal. But for situations where a developer wants to optimize for binary size instead, Rust provides mechanisms to accomplish this.

- [Build in Release Mode](https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust#build-in-release-mode)
- [Strip Symbols from Binary](https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust#strip-symbols-from-binary)
- [Optimize For Size](https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust#optimize-for-size)
- [Enable Link Time Optimization](https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust#enable-link-time-optimization-lto)
- [Reduce Parallel Code Generation Units to Increase Optimization](https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust#reduce-parallel-code-generation-units-to-increase-optimization)
- [Abort on Panic](https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust#abort-on-panic)
- [Remove panic String Formatting with panic_immediate_abort](https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust#remove-panic-string-formatting-with-panic_immediate_abort)
- [Remove core::fmt with #![no_main] and Careful Usage of libstd](https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust#remove-corefmt-with-no_main-and-careful-usage-of-libstd)
- [Removing libstd with #![no_std]](https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust#removing-libstd-with-no_std)
- [Compress the binary](https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust#compress-the-binary)

Most techniques described above are applicable to both native and WASM toolchains. Following that guide, it is possible to get a "hello world" binary around 93k.

And here is a specialized extensive article on [how to optimize the size of binary of Rust WASM build](http://cliffle.com/blog/bare-metal-wasm/).

And here is a deep discussion on the official Rust forum of the pros and cons of options developer has to [optimize binary by size](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/size-of-the-executable-binary-file-of-an-application/62160/17).