# Reduce application binary size in debug mode

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When I compile GTK4 "Hello World" application in rust I get binary with size 192Mb for debug mode. I use old SSD and I worry about it's resource as I compile and debug very frequently. I tried `-C prefer-dynamic` flag, but size of binary become 188Mb only.

Is this way to make application binary size much smaller?

PS: I work in win10 and use MSYS2.
PPS: I don't have problem with release build's size. With `-C link-arg=-s` and `lto = true` the size is about 200kb

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29008127/10113238) might be relevant to you.

Comment: @Smitop unfortunately this is not applicable for debug builds. For example adding `-C link-arg=-s` disable ability to debug

Comment: Debug builds are not meant to be small. Even their speed is not so important. So I'm afraid the answer is no.

Comment: @ChayimFriedma if I compile minimal "Hello World" example for GTK4 in C with full debug info and no optimization( `-g3 -O0`) I get only ~600kb exe-file.

Comment: Why does the debug build size matter for you?

Comment: @PitaJ I'm worried about my old SSD resource as it lost ~200Mb every time when I build the project

Comment: @ArtDen Because C is smaller than Rust - that does not means it's optimized there.