# Why Rust generates more no of assembly instructions than c for same use case?

Tags: c, linux, rust

### C

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
       char str1[5]="Hello",str2[]=" World!";
       strcat(str1,str2);
       puts(str1);
       return 0;
 }
```

Size of `.s` (assembler file) is 1K

### Rust

```
fn main() {
       let str1 = "Hello".to_string();
       let str2 = " World!".to_string();
       println!("{}", str1 + &str2);
}
```

Size of `.s` is 107K

Both compiled on Linux x86-64 platform.

Comment: Hint: Rust includes a substantial `std` standard library. C generally leans on a dynamically linked `libc`. Check out [`no_std`](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/intro/no-std.html), but keep in mind you lose a lot of features you otherwise take for granted.

Comment: your C code has a bug, a buffer overflow.

Comment: @tadman: `.s` is an assembly-language file, not an executable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah, thought that was a wonky `a.out` choice. Was having trouble understanding the phrasing.

Comment: and checking the size of the assembly file is kind of pointless, because there are directives, data, paddings... which are not really instructions

Comment: How have you created both `.s` files? What was the exact command in each case?

Comment: It would only be fair to compare binary sizes, not assembly file sizes, because assembly may include much more than just the code. You also need to have the same linkage and optimization options, as well as have both binaries stripped. To answer your question, compilation commands are important

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are Rust executables so huge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008127/why-are-rust-executables-so-huge/54842093#54842093) See also: [Removing libstd](https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust#removing-libstd-with-no_std).

Comment: Incidentally, these two programs don't do the same thing. `String` in Rust is a dynamic array of `u8` which is valid unicode, whereas `char *` in C is just `char *`.