# Why is rust's language feature "eh_personality" called "eh_personality"?

Tags: rust

I was reading about no-std Rust when I came across the `eh_personality` language feature. I was reading about it and noticed it is a crucial part of the unwinding stack, as well as being "mapped to GCC's personality function". Is there any history between the naming of Rust's and, optionally, GCC's personality functions?

Comment: No time to write an answer but see https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/estvau/til_why_the_eh_personality_language_item_is/

Comment: That's neat! I don't even know how I missed that in my initial searches. I'll leave some more time for anyone else to write an answer since I can't properly access any comments on that post at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/estvau/til_why_the_eh_personality_language_item_is/):

- eh is not an exclamation but rather an abbreviation of "exception handling".
- personality actually comes from its [C++ counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329059/what-is-gxx-personality-v0-for/329195#329195), which is traditionally named personality because it determines what type of exception handling to use (thus giving it a choice in what it does and furthermore a "personality" of sorts)

In summary, it's the "exception handling personality", or how the program will respond to an exception.