# How does `catch` statement recognize the type of exception without reflection?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

As we know, C++ does not have reflection. However, when we throw an error, `try-catch` can determine which type of exception you are throwing. How does it work without reflection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the C++ runtime determine the type of a thrown exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993262/how-does-the-c-runtime-determine-the-type-of-a-thrown-exception)

Comment: You are comparing compiler internals to what is offered to the programmer externally.  These are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although C++ does not have a reflection exposed to programmers, there is a type information known to compiler. In particular, when C++ program executes, there are special provisions made so that every time a try block is entered, a special entry is made (somewhere, for example, in exception frame) that the exception of the particular compile-time type is ready to be handled at this location. When exception is thrown, the frame is consulted for nearest suitable handler.