# Behavior of c++ exceptions escaping into c program

Tags: c++, c, exception, gcc

Lets say I have a shared library that is implemented in c++ but exposes a pure c interface. That library is then used in a c program.

**Does gcc make any guarantees about what happens, if an exception escapes from the c++ library into the c application?**
Will it e.g. always terminate the program?

I'm mainly interested in an answer for gcc on Linux on x64 and ARMv7-R, but answers about other operating systems, compilers and architectures are also welcome.

**EDIT:**
Just to make this clear: I'm not talking about letting exceptions pass through a c-function and then be caught in a calling c++ function or interaction with c or c++ callbacks. The application code itself is pure c. At some point it will call a function of the shared library (which internally is pure c++) and no application code will be called until that function returns. Also let's assume that I have no control over what flags are used to compile the application code.

Comment: I _believe_ that such an exception will be treated as an uncaught exception (i.e. generates call to `std::terminate`), unless the C code is compiled with `-fexceptions`, in which case the exception can propagate (although may still eventually be uncaught). I don't have a verifiable source for this however.

Comment: This is one reason why, if mixing C and C++, a common guideline is that the `main()` is compiled as C++, not as C and that `extern "C"` functions catch exceptions and don't let them propagate to the caller.  Either that, or the C++ code is compiled without exception support or doesn't throw at all.    The propagation of a C++ exception through a C function is undefined.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, I'm not happy with the situation, but it is what it is. The library is used by c programs - I can't change that. If I forget to catch some exception at the boundary program termination is - in general - acceptable for me (In particular, I usually don't try to recover from a `bad_alloc`), but I don't want to risk undefined behavior. So the question I'm facing is if I should wrap the implementation of all interface functions into an additional `try { ...} catch(...){ std::terminate(); }` block to be on the safe side or if I can rely on the compiler to produce the same effect.

Comment: @Peter: As gcc afaik defines some things that are undefined in the c++ standard in order to stay compatible with C, I hoped this was one of them.

Comment: @Peter: Do you have a source for *"The propagation of a C++ exception through a C function is undefined"* for gcc (It obviously can't be defined in the c++ standard)? If so I'd be happy to accept this an answer to my question.

Comment: @MikeMB for what it's worth I know that there is some level of cross-language support for exceptions in GCC, and compiling C code with `-fexceptions` will allow exceptions to propagate through it by generating unwind tables. Logically, a C++ `noexcept` function (which has no unwind tables) and a C function (compiled without `-fexceptions`) should appear similar to the unwind routine, which is why I assume you would then get `std::terminate`. But again, I have no authoritative reference.

Comment: @MikeMB - gcc 6.3 manual says `-fexceptions` allows "C code to interoperate with exception handlers written in C++", but is unspecific on what "interoperate" means. I suspect it allows an exception from C++ to pass through C code, and be caught in C++ code. It's less clear if it also means `std::terminate()` will be called with no C++ caller of the C code, or if any C caller is built without `-fexceptions`. Say, if a comparer passed to `qsort()` throws, it's unclear - without checking how libc is built - if the exception will pass properly through `qsort()`. Too many unknowns to be sure, IMHO.

Comment: @CloseVoters: Although you are not obliged to do so, it would still be nice to tell me what exactly is unclear about my question, so I can improve it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101390/will-c-exceptions-safely-propagate-through-c-code

Comment: In MinGW-w64 you can choose various exception mechanisms , I believe dwarf2 does not propagate through C code but SJLJ does. There are pros and cons to each exception method.

Comment: @M.M: Thanks for the contribution, but the linked post asks about propagation through c code to a c++ exception handler. I thought I made it clear that this is not what I'm asking about.

Comment: You would probably get a better answer to this question on the `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org` mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see about C++ exceptions, in [this example](https://godbolt.org/g/TsPi85) which I took [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh254939.aspx), GCC seems to include the following assembly in the catch statement:

```
    call    __cxa_end_catch
    jmp     .L37
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    call    __cxa_end_catch
    movq    %rbx, %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _Unwind_Resume
```

Which makes use of what I can only assume are C++ library calls to functions that deal with exceptions (e.g. `_Unwind_resume`). So if the C code links against your library it will have to provide these symbols/functions which means that the code is going to be entering the C++ library to deal with the exceptions.

However, I don't yet know what the C++ library requires in order to do its job. I would expect it to be self contained but I'm not certain of it.

*Edit: The answer to this question likely lies in the answers to the following two existing questions (and their interpretation):*

1. *[How is the C++ exception handling runtime implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490773/how-is-the-c-exception-handling-runtime-implemented)*
2. *[How are exceptions implemented under the hood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995734/how-are-exceptions-implemented-under-the-hood)*
3. *[How do exceptions work (behind the scenes) in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307610/how-do-exceptions-work-behind-the-scenes-in-c)*

**Edit 2:** From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307716/1667513), it seems that since `__cxa_throw` uses a table for keeping track of available handlers. I would assume that when the table is exhausted, *which in our case occurs when we enter C code*, the function would call `std::terminate`. Hence, the C++ runtime (against which you must have linked) should take care of this for you without you needing to put up a catch all clause.

Since I'm still uncertain I will write up a test of this theory and update the answer with the results.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm inclined to accept your answer but would feel better if it where backed - if not by official documentation - some tests.

Answer (score 1):

If a C++ exception escapes from the outermost `try` block (which can only be within the outermost C++ function call), then the exception cannot be caught.

An uncaught exception always results in termination by `std::terminate`, according to the C++ standard, §15.3/9.

Comment: Can the compiler - when compiling the shared library - assume that any exception that escapes through and "extern C" function is uncaught? Because after that it "enters" a c program, which is not governed by the c++ standard so I'm a bit reluctant to accept this explanation

Comment: @MikeMB No, because the `extern "C"` function may be called by a C++ function. `gcc` (as opposed to `g++`) even emits empty exception-handling tables in C libraries, though I don't know whether or why they're necessary.

Comment: So if there is no exception related code generated in the main application (because it is an C-Application) and the code inside the shared library doesn't know whether the exception will be cached or not - how does the runtime environment determine if it should terminate the app or not? An answer that is purely based on the c++ standard is imho not enough when talking about cross-language behavior and things like shared libraries which are both outside of the scope of the c++ standard.