# How C++ exception implemented (using Setjump() & Longjump() ?)

Tags: c++, exception

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How is the C++ exception handling runtime implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490773/how-is-the-c-exception-handling-runtime-implemented)
>   [How do exceptions work (behind the scenes) in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307610/how-do-exceptions-work-behind-the-scenes-in-c)

Dear All,

I want to know, how C++ exception is implemented ?

Is it actually using Setjump() & Longjump() concepts as in build?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490773/how-is-the-c-exception-handling-runtime-implemented

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307610/how-do-exceptions-work-behind-the-scenes-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490773/how-is-the-c-exception-handling-runtime-implemented

Answer (score 2):

The standard does not define how exceptions have to be implemented by the compiler vendors. The two main strategies are to keep track of catch locations in a table or to unwind the stack frames until a suitable catch site is found.

MSVC for example uses SEH (Structured Exception Handlers) to implement C++ exceptions, while GCC uses a pure address table approach. Other compilers still, may use stack unwinding if they preserve enough frame information.

Comment: MSVC uses SEH in 32-bit Windows for historical reasons. The 64-bit version uses a table approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should check Section 15.1 Throwing an exception of the standard.

Comment: @osdevkid: It's impossible to provide a link to the standard. ISO charges for it.

Comment: You can however view the latest drafts of each standard, which are for your purposes identical to the final document from ISO: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/