# c++ 'std::out_of_range'

Tags: c++, error-handling

Im trying opning a test file by using linked list. Part of code is such that

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

class isbn
{
    private:
    string code;
    int digit;

    public:
        //constructor
        isbn(): code(""), digit(0) { }

        //copy constructor
        isbn(const isbn &other):
        code(other.code),
        digit(other.digit) 
        {
            for(unsigned int i=0; i < (unsigned int) digit; i++)    
                code[i] = other.code[i];
        }
        void setCode(const char &temp);
        void setDigit(const int &num);

        isbn operator = (const isbn &other)
        {
            code = other.digit;
            digit = other.digit;
            for(unsigned int i=0; i < (unsigned int) digit; i++)    
            code[i] = other.code[i];
            return *this;
        }

};

void isbn::setCode(const char &temp)
{
    code = temp;
}
void isbn::setDigit(const int &num)
{
    digit = num;
}

void extIsbn_in_file(list<isbn> &isbns, const string &filename)
{
    ifstream filein;
    filein.clear();
    filein.open(filename.c_str());
    if(!filein)
    {
        cout << "error \n";
        exit(0);
    }
    cout << "\n";

    string contents;
    isbn aisbn;
    list<isbn>::iterator isbnitr;
    isbnitr = isbns.begin();
    int count = 0;

    while(!filein.eof())
    {
        getline(filein, contents, '\n');
        aisbn.setCode(contents.at(count));
        aisbn.setDigit(count);
        isbns.push_back(aisbn);
        count++;

    ..<more code>......
    ..<more code>......

    }
    filein.close();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if(argc > 0)
{
if(argc != 2)
{
cout << "invalid number of argument!! \n";
exit(0);
}
list<isbn> code;
extIsbn_in_file(code, argv[1]);
}
else
{
cout << "invalid number of argument!! \n";
exit(0);
}
return 0;
}
```

The Problem definetely happens when calling the given line

```
        aisbn.setCode(contents.at(count));
```

In this code, at method has been called but not pretty sure I did wrong with setCode() or attempt to use the at()

The error says 
             **what():  basic_string::at**
any ideas?

Comment: You're just trying to reimplement what the compiler does for you.

Comment: Sorry, I dont get you. Could you explain that?

Comment: The compiler will, in most cases, give you a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator that do memberwise copying if you don't provide your own copy constructor or copy assignment operator.

Comment: do i not have to put copy constrictor and assignment one?

Comment: still no luck after thorowing the constructors Just guess something wrongs at the at()

Comment: Run it in a debugger and watch what happens to `contents` and `count`.

Comment: I tested the test code that other compound is exctly the same with the code above and the test works fine                                                                `        int main()
 {
  const string contents = "dfskr-123 '\n' dsfjlkr-43289";

  test aisbn;
  list<test> simul;
  list<test>::iterator testitr;
  int count = 0;

  cout << contents << '\n';
  for(int i=0; i < (int)contents.length(); i++)
  {
   aisbn.setCode(contents.at(count));
   aisbn.setDigit(count+1);
   simul.push_back(aisbn);
   count++;
  }
  cout << contents << '\n';                        `Isnt it a bit wierd?

Comment: It's honestly too late to be looking for subtle bugs. I can tell you to make `i` a `std::string::size_type` or equivalent (`std::size_t`) instead of probably introducing possible data loss from `length()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is the C++ exception handling runtime implemented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490773/how-is-the-c-exception-handling-runtime-implemented)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i feel the variable `count` is going out of index.
just check `if(count < contents.size())` before calling `aisbn.setCode`

I see other flaws in the code, u are pushing same `aisbn` object again and again to `isbns` (`isbns.push_back(aisbn)`)

Comment: To avoit the second flaw, I removed aisbn.setDigit(count+1); Did I do all right?

Comment: it anyway gets out of "out of range" error. thanks