# My update takes so long to execute in C# but not in sql

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have this procedure :

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateVolunteers 
    @Vol_ID                   INT,
    @Vol_Name                 NVARCHAR(50),
    @Vol_Zone                 NVARCHAR(50),
    @vol_street               NVARCHAR(50),
    @Vol_Sex                  INT,
    @Vol_Date_of_Birth        DATE,
    @Vol_Home_Phone           INT,
    @Vol_Work_Phone           INT,
    @Vol_Mobile1              INT,
    @Vol_Mobile2              INT,
    @Vol_Email                NVARCHAR(50),
    @Vol_Job                  NVARCHAR(50),
    @Vol_Affiliation          NVARCHAR(50),
    @vol_Education            INT,
    @vol_Education_Place      NVARCHAR(50),
    @vol_Education_Department NVARCHAR(50),
    @vol_Interesting          INT,
    @Team_ID                  INT,
    @vol_Notes                NVARCHAR(50)
AS
    IF @team_id = -1
      BEGIN
          SET @team_id = NULL
      END

    UPDATE Personal_Info
    SET    Vol_Name = @Vol_Name,
           Vol_Zone = @Vol_Zone,
           vol_street = @vol_street,
           Vol_Sex = @Vol_Sex,
           Vol_Date_of_Birth = @Vol_Date_of_Birth,
           Vol_Home_Phone = @Vol_Home_Phone,
           Vol_Work_Phone = @Vol_Work_Phone,
           Vol_Mobile1 = @Vol_Mobile1,
           Vol_Mobile2 = @Vol_Mobile2,
           Vol_Email = @Vol_Email,
           Vol_Job = @Vol_Job,
           Vol_Affiliation = @Vol_Affiliation,
           vol_Education = @vol_Education,
           vol_Education_Place = @vol_Education_Place,
           vol_Education_Department = @vol_Education_Department,
           vol_Interesting = @vol_Interesting,
           Team_ID = @Team_ID,
           vol_Notes = @vol_Notes
    WHERE  Vol_ID = @Vol_ID
```

and I called it to C# application by this code:

```
 private static void UpdateVolunteer(string volID, string volName, string volZone,
 string volStreet, int volSex, DateTime volBirthday, int volHomePhone, 
 int volWorkPhone, int volMobile1, int volMobile2, string volEmail, 
 string volJob, string volAffiliation, int volEducation, 
 string volEducationPlace, string volEducationDepartment, int volInteresting, 
 int Team_ID, string volNotes)
 {
    try
    {
       SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("UpdateVolunteers", con);

       com.Parameters.Add("@Vol_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = volID;
       com.Parameters.Add("@Vol_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = volName;
       com.Parameters.Add("@Vol_Zone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = volZone;
       com.Parameters.Add("@vol_street", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = volStreet;
       com.Parameters.Add("@Vol_Sex", SqlDbType.Int).Value = volSex;
       com.Parameters.Add("@Vol_Date_of_Birth", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = volBirthday;
       com.Parameters.Add("@Vol_Home_Phone", SqlDbType.Int).Value = volHomePhone;
       com.Parameters.Add("@Vol_Work_Phone", SqlDbType.Int).Value = volWorkPhone;
       com.Parameters.Add("@Vol_Mobile1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = volMobile1;
       com.Parameters.Add("@Vol_Mobile2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = volMobile2;
       com.Parameters.Add("@Vol_Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = volEmail;
       com.Parameters.Add("@Vol_Job", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = volJob;
       com.Parameters.Add("@Vol_Affiliation", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = volAffiliation;
       com.Parameters.Add("@vol_Education", SqlDbType.Int).Value = volEducation;
       com.Parameters.Add("@vol_Education_Place", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = volEducationPlace;
       com.Parameters.Add("@vol_Education_Department", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = volEducationDepartment;
       com.Parameters.Add("@vol_Interesting", SqlDbType.Int).Value = volInteresting;
       com.Parameters.Add("@vol_Notes", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = volNotes;
       com.Parameters.Add("@Team_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
       com.Parameters["@Team_ID"].Value = Team_ID;

       com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
          con.Open();
          com.ExecuteNonQuery();
          con.Close();
   }
   catch (SqlException sqlEx)
   {
      if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
         con.Close();
         throw sqlEx;
   }
}
```

And this Function in C#: Called in Button_Click event

```
public void showVolunteers(int x)
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Vol_ID]
  ,[Vol_Name]
  ,[Vol_Zone]
  ,[vol_street]
  ,[Vol_Sex]
  ,[vol_Age]
  ,[Vol_Date_of_Birth]
  ,[Vol_Home_Phone]
  ,[Vol_Work_Phone]
  ,[Vol_Mobile1]
  ,[Vol_Mobile2]
  ,[Vol_Email]
  ,[Vol_Job]
  ,[Vol_Affiliation]
  ,[vol_Education]
  ,[vol_Education_Place]
  ,[vol_Education_Department]
  ,[vol_Interesting]
  ,[vol_Hours]
  ,[vol_Notes]
  ,[Team_ID]
  FROM [VolunteersAffairs].[dbo].[Personal_Info]", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet dats = new DataSet();
        da.SelectCommand = com;
        da.Fill(dats, "Personal_Info");
        dataGridViewX1.DataSource = dats.Tables["Personal_Info"];
        dataGridViewX1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "Nothing";
        updateComboBox.SelectedIndex = updateComboBox.Items.Count - 1;
        if (x != -1)
        {
            dataGridViewX1.Rows[x].Selected = true;
            dataGridViewX1.CurrentCell = dataGridViewX1[0, x];
        }
        labelItem1.Text = "Number of Volunteers = " + dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count;
        int X = 0, Y = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow n in dataGridViewX1.Rows)
        {
            if (n.Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "Male")
                X++;
            else
                Y++;
        }
        labelItem2.Text = "   |   Number of Males = " + X + " |Number of Female = " + Y;

        //When I put the following as a comment the update is so fast, else very slowly.
       //This operation takes the birthday of volunteers and calculate the age for every one. 
       //And calculate the age in runTime and the value of the column in database is null and always be.
        #region the problem has been detected here
        DateTime brithday;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewX1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            brithday = (DateTime)dataGridViewX1[6, i].Value;
            TimeSpan age = DateTime.Today - brithday;
            dataGridViewX1[7, i].Value = age.Days / 365;
        }
        #endregion

   }
```

The problem is that the code takes so long (about 1 min) to execute when I update the table via the form of C#, but it so fast when I update it via code in sql query. Is the problem in the code of C# or in the called procedure? 
Tell me what is the solution for this problem. Please!!

Comment: Have you tried using the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx Stopwatch class to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: Are you **sure** it's this code? If so, which line? Is it the `ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: What happens if you add `WITH RECOMPILE` before `AS` in your SP definition?

Comment: What is the column datatype of `Vol_ID`?

Comment: You can run Sql Profiler and see how soon the query reaches server

Comment: One easy thing to do is to make sure the **parameter definitions** of your stored procedure and your C# code calling it **match**, e.g. your stored procedure uses `@Vol_Name NVARCHAR(255)`, while your C# code uses `com.Parameters.Add("@Vol_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)` - try to use the **same datatype** and the **same length** for all parameters!

Comment: Also, you can debug step-by-step and see what operation is long

Comment: I don't see where code can be slow but a comment on your method: when you have so many parameters, you better create a class containing these and use that as parameter.

Comment: SORRY For Late, the internet has been crashed.

@Brad M What is that, I did not try it never.

@Yuriy Galanter| What did you mean by add `WITH RECOMPILE`

@neoistheone| you can find it before the last button in C# code.

@marc_s| OK I will, thanks for you advice.

@the| operation is long which that `com.ExecuteNonQuery();`

@T.S.| See the before last line in `TRY` in `C#`

Comment: @Martin Smith| int. why?!

Comment: @jim| How can I do it?

Comment: @ManyMar - Just on the off chance the column was datatype of lower precedence (e.g. `varchar`) and the mis matched dataypes were causing a scan rather than a seek.

Comment: @Martin Smith| I tried it but same so long to execute!!!!

Comment: @ManyMar knock me in skype "skvoznik", i can try to help ya

Comment: The problem has been detected as in update the question

Comment: The update is definitely not that much slower because of C#, I would look at any other calculated properties on your grid, or maybe you are also considering the time for the select?

Comment: @BlackTigerX| I calculate the age of each person in RunTime, Which the column Age in database is NULL and always be. just I want to see the age which has been calculated in RunTime and it does. The problem is in the last code you can see it now.

Answer (score -3):

You have this in a try catch block. Try catch blocks are expensive, and you probably don't need one to perform an sql query.

[try catch performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350264/try-catch-performance)

Instead of a try block, use a using block, which will instruct the garbage collector not to dispose the connection or command and the connection will be closed at the end of the using block as well.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  using (var command = new SqlCommand("UpdateVolunteers", connection))
  {
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vol_ID", volID);
    // other paramters...

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think using blocks would boost performance as you may think

Comment: `Using` blocks compile to try/catch/finally.

Comment: Same as before too long