# How do exceptions work (behind the scenes) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch, throw

Identical to "[How do exceptions work (behind the scenes) in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307610/how-do-exceptions-work-behind-the-scenes-in-c1.)", but for **C#**.

I know that the steps below have to be performed when an exception is thrown.

1. Find the nearest handler for the exception type;
2. Unwind the stack up to the handler level;
3. Call the handler;
4. Find and call every `finally` blocks.

How does .NET handles these operations? How does the mapping for the "current" handlers work? How much code is emitted in a try/catch block? And in a throw block?

Answer (score 4):

.NET exceptions on Windows use the OS' underlying [Structured Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657(VS.85).aspx) (SEH) mechanism, in the same way as native code. As listed in the [linked question for C (and C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307610/how-do-exceptions-work-behind-the-scenes-in-c).

Answer (score 3):

.NET exceptions use the underlying Windows structured exception handling implementation, though this is *not* a requirement. Mono may do it differently.

In fact, if you write a single-line Console app that just throws an exception, and then run it in Windbg, you'll see the hook into the unmanaged exception handling.