# Catch statements are being completely ignored

Tags: c++, exception

I've run into a situation with some code I inherited... honestly, I believe the code is written correctly, but this error still seems to manifest.

I'll quickly note that the code is cross-compiled from linux to LynxOS, I'm not sure if that can have anything to do with the error.

Basically, in one specific case:

```
try {
    std::vector<ClassA> x = SomeGeneratingFunction();

    //We get to here fine.  X may be empty/unpopulated though.
    if (x.size() < 1)
    {
        throw(MyException("It crashed."));
    }
}
catch (MyException e)
{
    //Handle it.
}
catch (...)
{
    //Handle it.
}
```

We throw given the vector is unpopulated, but for some reason the throw bypasses the catch clauses - both of them.  It only seems to happen here - though we woudln't usually do it form an if statement scope, but that should be completely irrelevant since its still in the try scope.

PS:  The code below is actually the contents of a function, and exceptions come out of the function when called even though they should all be handled by the catch blocks.

Any ideas how this is possible?  And yes, this isn't the real code/exception classes, but the exception class is the simple example you'd google of overloading std::exception, and the SomeGeneratingFunction() does return a good vector, even if it is empty.  I cannot provide the real code, but this is exceedingly close barring any little typos I may have made writitng it off the top of my head.

Comment: I have no idea but consider writing the catch line as this *catch (const MyException& e)* to avoid having to pay for MyException copy constructor because you'll get a copy of that *throw* threw.

Comment: if you add debugging statment (before the conditional, before and after the throw) does it change the behavior?  what if you take the vector out of the picture?  What does GDB do when you run with a  'catch throw' ?    How do you compile?  Try mucking with optimization flags

Comment: Debugging statements print as expected and don't change the behavior.  It's a massive system with a complex make heirarchy and lots of flags used in the different portions - but more importantly, we use try catches everywhere you should (or attempt to) and haven't seen this situation before.  I thought maybe the cross compiler could have messed something up with scoping or something like that, but I don't know enough about compilers.  I've had a few people look it over - we can work around it by doing if else instead of if/throw, but it's worrying to work around something that shoudln't happen

Comment: What is `Try`, with a capital 'T'? Is that just a typo?

Comment: Also, you might try `x.empty()` instead of `x.size() < 1`.

Comment: @w00te: Are you sure that exception is actually thrown? Is it caught somewhere else?

Comment: Can you tell if the `MyException` object is being constructed?

Comment: Would finally() catch it as a test case?

Comment: @Michael: It might, if C++ had `finally`.

Comment: *"...and exceptions come out of the function when called..."*: Are the escaping exceptions of type MyException?

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer the question. I shoved the posted code into a `main` function, added some `#include` and some minimal definitions for `MyException`, `ClassA` and `SomeGeneratingFunction` and `catch` worked as expected for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the `catch (...)` clause didn't catch the exception, my answer does not solve the OP's problem. But for others that found this question on SO, maybe my answer is useful, because it explains why the first catch failed.

I had a similar issue where my `catch(const std::exception& ex)` was just not working. It turned out to be a dumb problem in that I was switching between C# and C++ exceptions, and in C# you need to specify `new` when you throw your exception, while in C++ you normally don't (but you can, but in this case you are throwing a pointer and not a reference). I was accidentally doing

```
throw new std::runtime_error("foo");
```

so

```
catch(std::exception*  ex)
```

would have caught it but

```
catch(std::exception& ex)
```

doesn't. Of course, the solution is just remove the new statement, as that is not the traditional design pattern in C++.

Comment: Exact same problem occurred in my code! Had been googling for the possible reasons for a lot of time and in the end turned out to be the same dumb mistake you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a spare set of parentheses around the exception object in the `throw` statement, it looks like a function call. Is there any possibility that you've defined a function called `throw`? The parameter to the exception constructor keeps this from being a victim of the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), but that's a possibility if your actual code differs from your example.

Comment: `throw` is a keyword, you can't define a function with that name.

Comment: `throw MyException()` or `throw(MyException())` couldn't possible be a vexing parse because throw is a keyword, not type name. I don't know of any C++ compilers that don't complain if you try to use `throw` as the name of a function.

Comment: @interjay I thought about that, but maybe there's some perverse situation where `throw` was redefined by a macro? I agree it's grabbing at straws, but desperate problems call for desperate solutions.

Comment: Well, I like the idea.  I do think its some sort of compiler glitch with the cross-compilation by this point.  I've had alot of very compotent people check it out to no avail.  Anyway, I tried your suggestion and it didn't seem to change anything - but thank you, it was an interesting thought! :)  I probably won't get a solution to this one, but I'll leave it up for a while longer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (MyException e)
```

should read:

```
catch (const MyException &e)
```

I'm not sure why your throw looks like a function either, kind of bizarre.

Edit:

I've had problems with catches based on something similar, though I agree that it isn't sufficient in this toy case.

The compiler seems off to me, is `Try` defined as something funny?  If it were empty it *could* make sense if your compiler ignored catch statements with no try.

Comment: Wouldn't that just make it more efficient by stopping the copy from forming, or would the original exception actually propogate out of the function without it?

Comment: This _could_ be the problem if `MyException` isn't copyable (although compilers are probably required to issue a diagnostic for that), but I think this is _highly unlikely_. (Oh, and catching by `const` reference is even better.)

Comment: Catching by reference might be a better practice (and, as @sbi noted, in that case it should be `catch (const MyException &e)`), it isn't the original problem.

Comment: @w00te: If you don't catch by reference you are susceptible to the slicing problem. This is when a class derived from MyException is thrown and subsequently caught by value with MyException, the resulting copy construction will slice the derived part out of the object.

Comment: @Martin: whether there is slicing or not (i.e. if what you catch is what was really thrown), the fact is that the exception would be caught in one of the handlers.

Comment: @sbi, if `MyException` wasn't copyable you wouldn't be able to `throw` it. A `throw` always makes a copy.

Comment: @Mark: Yeah, there's that. I forgot. `<sigh/>`

Comment: @David Rodríguez: I was just trying to answer w00te question in the comment above. The use of reference in this context has no bearing on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **function** `MyException` in a smaller scope (possibly even by accident, Most Vexing Parse) then `throw MyException("It crashed")` will call that function and throw the return value.

Answer (score -3):

Let me slash the problem... Don't use exceptions in C++ unless you want to crash definitely the program. I know exceptions may be quite useful, but they have very poor performances because it raises up an hardware exception which is caught by the operating system kernel. Using return values and error codes can be 500 times faster than throwing and catching exceptions.

Comment: Why ? This is a design recommendation. I did benchmarks to verify that and another programmer of my team did look at the generated assembly to understand exceptions mechanism. What we found may be surprising, but the problem is serious.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307610/how-do-exceptions-work-behind-the-scenes-in-c

Comment: Faster is not synonymous with more stable.

Comment: It is possible to create intelligent structures which will check that an error code has been read or not. Using that mechanism you have the same stability as with the exceptions. Plus, there may be hard to track bugs when an exception is thrown during another exception handling. Concerning performances, exceptions do not add any overhead if they are not thrown - however, using exception for example to check correctness of user input is a bad design. Exceptions must be only "exceptional" and avoided as much as possible.

Answer (score -3):

I would just rewrite it without using try/catch. Doesn't seem appropriate to use try/catch here anyway. For all you know, exceptions may not work on your target platform.

Comment: That's what I did do, but I'd like to understand what's broken about them since they're used in alot of other places and seem to work fine - other code might have to be adjusted.

Comment: This isn't really a solution to my question, but its the thing I had to do in the end so I'll mark it, haha.  Marking up the other answers with info I found helpful too.

Comment: This doesn't _at all_ address the concern by the OP.