# C++ exception overhead and throw instruction

Tags: c++, try-catch, throw

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do exceptions work (behind the scenes) in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307610/how-do-exceptions-work-behind-the-scenes-in-c)

I know that the try/catch blocks can add a little overhead during the runtime. But is it the case for a single "throw" instruction with no try/catch blocks ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the throw without try/cache, then the throw is meaningless and cause the application crash.

Comment: It isn't meaningless; it provides the coder with a clear description of why the program's execution stopped, assuming the coder uses something that prints it. It's always possible to go out of bounds of an array etc. by mistake.